# Hadoop 2.8 NodeManager is shutting down on windows

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, nodemanager

**I have followed all the steps from this website. On my PC all are running perfectly but on my laptop nodeManager is shutting down.**

https://muhammadbilalyar.github.io/blogs/How-to-install-Hadoop-on-Window-10/?fbclid=IwAR3u_-xwIulzm9KJ7ivsPD_JyQWI0jPvV9s_Fhp1RpPFupY3LWvrulzRr_4

**Following is my nodeManager status after running start-all.cmd command.**

```
r class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.Res
ourceLocalizationService$LocalizerTracker
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO containermanager.AuxServices: Adding auxiliary service ma
preduce_shuffle, "mapreduce_shuffle"
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl:  Using ResourceCalculatorP
lugin : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.ResourceCalculatorPlugin@2b72cb8a
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl:  Using ResourceCalculatorP
rocessTree : null
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Physical memory check enab
led: true
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Virtual memory check enabl
ed: true
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO util.ProcfsBasedProcessTree: ProcfsBasedProcessTree curre
ntly is supported only on Linux.
19/11/27 12:42:00 INFO monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: ContainersMonitor enabled:
 true
19/11/27 12:42:01 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to
be 11. Got 7
19/11/27 12:42:01 WARN monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: NodeManager's totalPmem co
uld not be calculated. Setting it to -1
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Nodemanager resources:
 memory set to 8192MB.
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Nodemanager resources:
 vcores set to 8.
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Initialized nodemanage
r with : physical-memory=8192 virtual-memory=17204 virtual-cores=8
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO util.JvmPauseMonitor: Starting JVM pause monitor
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.co
ncurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 2000 scheduler: class org.apache.had
oop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 51483
19/11/27 12:42:01 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to
be 11. Got 7
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.had
oop.yarn.api.ContainerManagementProtocolPB to the server
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Blocking new conta
iner-requests as container manager rpc server is still starting.
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 51483: starting
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO security.NMContainerTokenSecretManager: Updating node add
ress : annupc:51483
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.co
ncurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 500 scheduler: class org.apache.hado
op.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.had
oop.yarn.server.nodemanager.api.LocalizationProtocolPB to the server
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Localizer started
on port 8040
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8040
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8040: starting
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
19/11/27 12:42:01 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Permissions incorr
ectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x,
 actual value = rwxrwxr-x
19/11/27 12:42:01 INFO localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Attempting to init
ialize /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir
19/11/27 12:42:02 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Permissions incorr
ectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x,
 actual value = rwxrwxr-x
19/11/27 12:42:02 WARN localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Failed to setup lo
cal dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions incorrectly
set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actua
l value = rwxrwxr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1560)

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService$1.onDirsChanged(ResourceLocalizationService.java:271
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.registe
rDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.reg
isterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerM
anagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(No
deManager.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNod
eManager(NodeManager.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManage
r.java:684)
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.s
erver.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService failed
in state STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException:
 Failed to setup local dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as g
ood.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to setup local di
r /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService$1.onDirsChanged(ResourceLocalizationService.java:271
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.registe
rDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.reg
isterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerM
anagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(No
deManager.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNod
eManager(NodeManager.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManage
r.java:684)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions i
ncorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-
xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1560)

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1528)
        ... 13 more
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 8040
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 8040
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Public cache exiti
ng
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.s
erver.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state STARTED;
 cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to setup
local dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to setup local di
r /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService$1.onDirsChanged(ResourceLocalizationService.java:271
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.registe
rDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.reg
isterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerM
anagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(No
deManager.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNod
eManager(NodeManager.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManage
r.java:684)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions i
ncorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-
xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1560)

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1528)
        ... 13 more
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping server on 51483
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server listener on 51483
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in st
ate STARTED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Fail
ed to setup local dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to setup local di
r /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService$1.onDirsChanged(ResourceLocalizationService.java:271
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.registe
rDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.reg
isterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerM
anagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(No
deManager.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNod
eManager(NodeManager.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManage
r.java:684)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions i
ncorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-
xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1560)

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1528)
        ... 13 more
19/11/27 12:42:02 WARN nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.ya
rn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics syst
em...
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stoppe
d.
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdo
wn complete.
19/11/27 12:42:02 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to setup local di
r /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService$1.onDirsChanged(ResourceLocalizationService.java:271
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.registe
rDirsChangeListener(DirectoryCollection.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.reg
isterLocalDirsChangeListener(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.serviceStart(ResourceLocalizationService.java:371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerM
anagerImpl.serviceStart(ContainerManagerImpl.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeServ
ice.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(No
deManager.java:369)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:
193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNod
eManager(NodeManager.java:637)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManage
r.java:684)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions i
ncorrectly set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-
xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkLocalDir(ResourceLocalizationService.java:1560)

        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.
ResourceLocalizationService.checkAndInitializeLocalDirs(ResourceLocalizationServ
ice.java:1528)
        ... 13 more
19/11/27 12:42:02 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at annupc/192.168.1.103
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the following bin files in HADOOP directory

https://github.com/s911415/apache-hadoop-3.1.0-winutils

also, try to clean datanode files and remove temp from C:\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which I think is caused because of permission of the folders required to run Hadoop. When I tried the same commands in Administrator command prompt(opened through run as administrator), It worked for me.
And if you are working in ubuntu, typing sudo before the command might help.

Answer (score -1):

It clearly states the reason for shut down.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Permissions incorrectly
set for dir /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache, should be rwxr-xr-x, actual value = rwxrwxr-x

```
chmod -R 755 /tmp/hadoop-anwar/nm-local-dir/usercache
```

should solve the issue.